# How to perform encryption/decryption in a RESTful system?

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes

I'm not a crypto/security expert and have designed an architecture for encryption/decryption. I'm not sure if its full proof and want to know what people use as industry standard?

I'm trying to perform encryption/decryption in RESTful api where client sends encrypted payload and server decrypts it and does some processing. The server then sends encrypted response which the client decrypts and does some processing.

The architecture I've decided is:

- One of the server periodically(once in 24hrs) generates a RSA keypair and uploads encrypted private key to redis so that other servers  can get it and use decrypted private key from a master key.
- create an api to share current active public key.

client:

- get current active public key from server as raw text
- generate new symmetric key
- encrypt request with symmetric key
- encrypt symmetric key with public key
- encrypt iV with public key
- send request

server:

- decrypt iV with private key
- decrypt symmetric key with private key
- decrypt payload with symmetric key
- encrypt response with symmetric
- send response

client:

- decrypt response with symmetric key

I'm using `java.security` and `javax.crypto` for all the key generation, cipher encryption/decryption.

The transformations I'll be doing is

- RSA transformation `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding`
- AES transformation `AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding`

Is this architecture okay to use? The reason for creating an api to get public key is so that we can do key rotation periodically. Also, I'll create an admin only api to force change the RSA key pair incase private key leak.

My major concern is the api that shares naked public key. Is this a valid approach and what are its problems? What are my options otherwise? Any help would be greatly appreciated because this is a very new topic for me and I am finding it very interesting!

Update

- I'm using TLS/SSL for communication and want to add additional level of encryption

Comment: Why aren't you using TLS?

Comment: @Marc I'm, I want to perfrom encryption ontop of it

Comment: TLS already provides privacy, data integrity, and authentication (either one or both ways). Why isn't that sufficient? You don't need to re-encrypt data in transit that is already using TLS.

Comment: @Marc, because I need to send really sensitive data from client to server and vice versa,, any breach to the network would result in naked payloads?

Comment: If TLS with good ciphers and key strengths is broken (all of which are configured by you), why would your custom encryption be any better?

Comment: @Marc, would TLS still be secure if a proxy is being used? Such that, the data doesn't really go from the client to the server, but goes via a middle proxy which has it's own SSL certificate handshake, in which case it can and will be able to read the sensitve info right? Thinking out loud here.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a TLS-terminating proxy you don't control. Even if you do have one, it's recommended to terminate TLS at the backend.

Comment: in a hypothetical realm, where it's being used, what can we do to solve this? i was also looking at [mastercards lib](https://github.com/Mastercard/client-encryption-java/) and found out that they're using it. their reason is, that android can read you data internally. as before it hands over the data to the network layer, it passes through their own layer for checking of apps stealing personal info. thus they've added this on their api directly.

Comment: "it passes through their own layer ..."? Really? You're going to have to back up that claim. If instead you want to argue that the OS can access your data, sure, it has access to all memory contents. Throwing more encryption wouldn't help. And this is getting away from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you already have TLS, so this won't add any security, it'll just slow things down.

You mention sharing a private key between servers. Don't do that. Ever. Generate individual key pairs for every server, and have your central server sign them (the usual certificate generation process, with your central server as the CA).

The method you've proposed is otherwise OK but slow. Why not try libsodium boxes? Then it's a matter of calling crypto_box_easy() on the sender side, and crypto_box_open_easy() on the receiver side (obviously after key/nonce generation and exchange of public key from receiver to sender). There are bindings for Java.

Comment: But if I don't share the key pairs among servers, how will the client get the right public key? the load balancer will cycle through the servers and so the client will get a public key from one server and sent the request to a differnt server which has a different private key?

Comment: Also, i did ask about libsodium and java crypto on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121422/what-is-the-difference-between-libsodium-and-javax-crypto

Comment: The load balancer won't interrupt an existing connection. Perform the exchange within a single connection.

Comment: As for why I recommend libsodium, it prevents mistakes (like using RSA encryption) that Java's built in crypto library makes easy.

Comment: I still don't understand how we can transfer public key from server to client and client send us encrypted data all in a single connection because we have a restful system and we don't maintain any sessions on the server.

cool, I'll have a look at libsodium

Comment: You have a TLS (and thus TCP) connection straight from client to server. Not from client to load balancer. The same mechanism works for any layers you add over it. Just because it's RESTful doesn't mean there's no TCP session.

Comment: Can you provide a reference on how to pass data multiple times with the same connection preferably on spring boot framework (but any will do,, this does make sense logically but I've not seen an implementation)? I was only aware of the normal flow i.e client creates a tcp connection to server with handshake, then after the setup, cleint sends request, waits for response, server sends response and terminates connection.

Comment: you must be talking about Http persistent connections? thanks alot :D